# I would like to see the source code of this $.get() ajax function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to see the source of the function $.get() [This one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

How can I proceed to do that, I downloaded the Jquery 1.7 developer version but could not find this function inside it by any means...

Comment: See my answer. also just search for `get` in the code. You will find it ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are an alias to the $.ajax function. Look around line 7150 in this file

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
        // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        return jQuery.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: callback,
            dataType: type
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

And **here you go :-D**: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.get

```
function (url, data, callback, type) {
    // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
    if (jQuery.isFunction(data)) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for the code that starts with this:
For [jQuery 1.7.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) the method starts with:

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
```

It just passes off the call to `jQuery.ajax`.